# Generate header and trailer with empty file

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

I have a workflow that takes output containing customer data, sorts it (via a router transformation) according to the system in which the customer is found, and generates flat files for each system. It also generates header and trailer files for each system, and I combine the header, detail and trailer files via a post-session command.

The problem is that there's a requirement for me to generate "empty" system files where there are no records - i.e just a header and trailer with nothing between. But because the header and trailer files are being generated via the router, for systems with no records I get no output at all - not even the header or trailer. (I have to generate at least the header via the router as it contains the system name.)

I can't think of a way to separate out the header and trailer from the router and still get accurate data for the system and the row count for the trailer. Ideas?

Comment: How are you generating the header and trailer files? Could you tell us more about the mapping flow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up assigning the row count in the detail files to a variable, then generating headers and trailers in a subsequent flow. This way the header/trailer files are always generated, and since the variable has an initial value of 0 it's still accurate if there are no detail rows.

Answer (score 0):

There are different options:

- create the header before the router and send it to all outputs - each
  target will then always be created
- echo your header and trailer via command line, so this will create a file
- before the router union one line (make it either empty if that's ok, or have it removed as part of the post-session command)

It would be nice to have some more details on how you create the whole output.